# Logs : client side and server side logging

Tags: java, log4j

I need to implement logging in my project. I am using log4j for it. My project has a client side which sends call to server then all process happens at server side. I am not sure how to include both client side and server side logging in same log.

Comment: Why would you need the server-side logs to reach the client side (or vice versa)?

Comment: no, i want to store both server side and client side log at one place

Comment: What is the call interface? EJB?

Comment: not EJB, everthing is on local server. Call starts from one client which is fetching data from one server and sends the info to another local server ......are you able to get it :) ?

Comment: What is the call interface?